# Pop-up form does not go visible

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, popup

Recently I wanted to make a pop-up form with Ajax and Bootstrap. To do this I got this code from a tutorial site. Then I noticed that my code does not pop up anything when I clicked the first Login button(It should work that way according to the tutorial). Is my code missing something or it is clearly wrong? I am only a beginner. Please help. Here is my code:

index.php

```
<?php   
 session_start();  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Make Login Form by Using Bootstrap Modal with PHP Ajax Jquery</title>  
           <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />  
           <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Make Login Form by Using Bootstrap Modal with PHP Ajax Jquery</h3><br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <?php  
                if(isset($_SESSION['username']))  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <h1>Welcome - <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1><br />  
                     <a href="#" id="logout">Logout</a>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                ?>  
                <div align="center">  
                     <button type="button" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                }  
                ?>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
   <!-- Modal content-->  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <label>Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" class="btn btn-warning">Login</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#login_button').click(function(){  
           var username = $('#username').val();  
           var password = $('#password').val();  
           if(username != '' && password != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"action.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data: {username:username, password:password},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          //alert(data);  
                          if(data == 'No')  
                          {  
                               alert("Wrong Data");  
                          }  
                          else  
                          {  
                               $('#loginModal').hide();  
                               location.reload();  
                          }  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                alert("Both Fields are required");  
           }  
      });  
      $('#logout').click(function(){  
           var action = "logout";  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"action.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{action:action},  
                success:function()  
                {  
                     location.reload();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

action.php

```
 <?php  
 session_start();  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database1");  
 if(isset($_POST["username"]))  
 {  
      $query = "  
      SELECT * FROM admin_login  
      WHERE admin_name = '".$_POST["username"]."'  
      AND admin_password = '".$_POST["password"]."'  
      ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];  
           echo 'Yes';  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'No';  
      }  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["action"]))  
 {  
      unset($_SESSION["username"]);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: @BilalAhmed can you tell me where exactly I should add this?

Comment: The code is fine, I copied and pasted that code and got the pop-up to show immediately. Do you get any console errors (Inspect Element)?

Comment: @DavidPicksley you are right. it's working fine, check your console and find error on console

Comment: How to check errors? I am using notepad++ and xampp

Comment: right click on browser (where you execute code) and click inspect (last option in chrome) and then go console tab. and also you can google (how to open console in browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have implemented the code for everything but not for opening the modal. Add this to your script

```
$("#login").on('click',function(){
    `$("loginModal").modal('show');`
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I should add this? For example write into fragment of my code and send it

Answer (score 0):

Your code working perfectly mistake in CSS your popup will be hide for ".fade:not(.show)" class used  "opacity:0" you will be increased you "opacity:10" according your requirement.

change below CSS:

```
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```